# Java 2d Array print out index at certain element

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say i got this :

```
int b[][];
b = new int[4][4];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
        b[i][j] = (Math.random() * 10);
    }
}
```

And i want to print out at which `[i][j]` the value is `< 5`, how would i do this?

Comment: use an `if` statement, along with a proper **Java Tutorial**

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. tried using if statement before but didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You should to cast the value to `int`, because `Math.random()` return a `double` and not an `int`, and you have to use if to check if your value is `< 5` or not, You can use this, :

```
...
for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
    b[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    if(b[i][j] < 5){
        System.out.println(b[i][j]);
    }
}
...
```

Or you can use :

```
if ((b[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10)) < 5) {...}
//--^--Initialization and test in one shot-^---------
```

Answer (score 0):

You are knowing the for loop but not knowing the if statement is something weird.

But still for your knowledge 
You can try out something like this

```
public class SomeClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Double b[][]  = new Double [4][4];

        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++ ){
                    for(int j=0;j<b[i].length;j++){
                     b[i][j]=(Math.random()*10);
                     if(b[i][j] < 5){
                        System.out.println("\n[i][j] = "+"["+i+"]["+j+"]\t result = "+b[i][j]);
                     }
                }
                }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You already know how to iterate over the 2D array. Just put a `if` clause within the inner loop with your condition and call `print` with the indexes `i` and `j`

Comment: you shouldn't really do people's homework. We are not here to save them a couple of keystrokes. These kind of answers bring along downvotes, even though they are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Shashwat